# Using public static function in mysqli functions

Tags: php, mysqli, static, static-methods

I am creating a site which connects to database using public static function.
As it is called by class name i can't understand how will i execute `mysqli_query()`. Below is the code:

**db.class.php**

```
<?php
class connect
{
    private static $db_host='localhost';

    private static $db_user='root';

    private static $db_pass='';

    private static $db_name='i_constuddoer01';

    //using public static function to avoid overloading
    public static function cxn_mysqli() {
        $result=mysqli_connect(self::$db_host,self::$db_user,self::$db_pass,self::$db_name);
        if(!$result)
            header("Location: sorry.php");
        else 
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
require_once('db.class.php');

function addUser($fname,$lname,$email,$pass) {
    $query="INSERT INTO users VALUES(...)";
    $qr_status = mysqli_query(connect::cxn_mysqli(),$query)
}
```

What should I do, is there any other way?

Comment: Do you just want to use the existing connect class? Or are you writing this class and do you want feedback on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what your trying to do is create a singleton class, below is an example of one

```
class Connect
{
    private static $instance;

    # make the construct private to avoid anyone using new Connect()
    private function __construct()
    {
        # Sql connect code in here
    }

    static public function i()
    {
        if(!is_object(self::$instance)) {
            return new self;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}

# Lets try to create two instances
$i = Connect::i();
$j = Connect::i();

# Oh look they are exactly the same object
echo spl_object_hash($i)."\n";
echo spl_object_hash($j)."\n";
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Since mysqli has persistent connections by default, why should we use a singleton for mysqli?